# How to write out nested key YAML from TCL?

Tags: dictionary, yaml, tcl

I am looking for template as below. I tried dict2yaml which is not giving YAML format as below.
Can someone help?

```
LEVEL_1:
         LEVEL_2:
                 LEVEL_3: some_value
```

Another varient is

```
LEVEL_1:
         LEVEL_2:
                 LEVEL_3:
                        - some_value1
                        - some_value2
                        - some_value3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good example where Tcl's type system is not helpful to you.  Any list with an even number of items could be considered a dict.

For example:

```
set nested_dict {key1 {key2 {x y}}}
```

is `y` the value of a dict with three nested keys or is `{x y}` the value of a dict with two nested keys?

The `yaml::dict2yaml` function only works for simple dicts with no nested keys.

One possibility is to convert your nested dict into a "huddle" https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/huddle and then use `yaml::huddle2yaml`.

It might be simpler to just iterate over the nested keys and handle indenation yourself.  This is assuming you know the structure of the nested dict.

```
set nested_dict {key1 {key2 {x y}}}

dict for {k1 d1} $nested_dict {
    puts "$k1:"
    dict for {k2 d2} $d1 {
        puts "    $k2:"
        dict for {k3 val} $d2 {
            puts "        $k3: $val"
        }
    }
}
```

which prints out:

```
key1:
    key2:
        x: y
```

An example with huddles:

```
package require huddle
package require yaml
      
set MyHuddle [huddle create]
huddle set MyHuddle LEVEL_1 [huddle create]
huddle set MyHuddle LEVEL_1 LEVEL_2 [huddle create] 
huddle set MyHuddle LEVEL_1 LEVEL_2 LEVEL_3 [huddle list some_value1 some_value2 some_value3]

yaml::huddle2yaml $MyHuddle
```

which prints out:

```
---
LEVEL_1:
  LEVEL_2:
    LEVEL_3:
      - some_value1
      - some_value2
      - some_value3
```

Please read the huddle man page carefully.   `huddle create` and `huddle set` are very similar to `dict create` and `dict set`.   However, I found that I needed to explicitly create a huddle below LEVEL_1 and LEVEL2 before I could set the LEVEL_3 key's value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you share an example with huddle? I tried that but it has its own challenges. One I faced that we have to create object first either as dictionary, string or list. Then if I tried to use huddle set or append it expects specific data type

Comment: I edited my answer to show a huddle example.

Comment: Thank you, it worked..!!